# .NET core External Authentication - Get extra info from Twitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, twitter, asp.net-core

I have successfully implemented the Twitter Authentication in my .net core project. in the ExternalLoginCallback (Account Controller), I am receiving the access_token and access_token_secret after successful authentication with twitter.

How am I meant to use those to call the twitter REST API in order to receive further information about the user?

It looks like the API needs different keys for the authorisation.. See here:

Authorization:

> OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxx",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="xxxxxxxxxxx",
>   oauth_nonce="xxxxxxxxxxx",
>   oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
>   oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxx"

I have replaced all values with xxxx..

Hope you can provide me with the missing puzzle piece!

Thanks, Nik

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building the autorization string property.

The last step is to send the request to the Twitter endpoint, setting the value of the  header to your authorization string.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests